# FTP is connect but directory is not displaying

Tags: ftp, cpanel

I have 2 network connections. one is idea and another is Reliance. When i use idea then it working very well but when i am using Reliance internet connection then it showing timeout error.

```
Status: Resolving address of royaleimpex.in
Status: Connecting to 208.91.198.76:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Resolving address of royaleimpex.in
Status: Connecting to 208.91.198.76:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 5 of 150 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 10:01. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 5 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 AUTH TLS OK.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issues with the FTP passive port, Please contact your server admin and ask them to enable passive port in your server firewall and FTP configuration,